# What is the default stop value for a_list [-1: :-1]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, slice

I have this piece of code:

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6]

print (a_list[::-1]) 
print (a_list[-1::-1])
print (a_list[5::-1])
print (a_list[-1:0:-1])
```

and the output is:

```
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Because step size is negative, the default start is at 5 or -1 index, so the first three statements give the same output.
But when I was trying to figure out what the stopping point is I tried `print (a_list[-1:0:-1])` and it obviously excludes the value at `0` index which is `1`.
also, the index before `0` is `-1`, and because it's the same as the starting point it gives an empty list.
So my question is, what is the default stop point for  `a_list [ : :-1]`? Or more generally,  what is the default for `any_list[start:stop:step]` with a negative step size?

Comment: Please read about slices [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

Comment: @555Russich thanks! I found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing#:~:text=What%20really%20annoys,at%2014%3A22)

Answer (score 0):

When explicitly defined, the stop is **excluded**.

So in your first three example all remaining values are used, however in the last one (`a_list[-1:0:-1]`), `0` is excluded.